# Schrödinger's "Award bounty" button

Tags: bug, design, bounties, mobile-web

Let's play a small game first:

#### Illustration: Has the bounty been awarded?

Here are two images cut from two screenshots. One of them has an **active** bounty, while the other has an **awarded** bounty. Make your guess base on the images!

[image: Guess 1]
[image: Guess 2]

Haha I bet you can't, so here's the answer:

> [Original post for Picture 1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152790) and the original (uncut) screenshot:
>  [image: Answer 1]
>
>  [Original post for Picture 2](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/82642) and the original (uncut) screenshot:
>  [image: Answer 2]

Actually they look identical! Shouldn't that be changed and make unawarded bounty (the "award" button) look lighter like the grey tick for "accept this answer" button do?

Comment: I retracted the answer acception because that's not the answer I want, I accepted it just for the screenshot.

Comment: Anyway... I chose the tags carefully. The title is more for fun but the actual problem is at the bottom.

Comment: But you're are the only one who sees the *award bounty* option, right? So this only is an issue for the user setting and having to award the bounty, right?

Comment: @rene Then why differentiate the grey tick from the green tick (accepting answers)?

Comment: Yeah, that is true ...

Comment: +1 for the question wrote like a puzzle, entertaining to see

Comment: I donno remember exactly but I think it appear in light color but when you hover over it, it will change to it's original color

Comment: @OptimusPrime Be serious. This is a bug about [tag:mobile-web], not desktop web.