# Mobile site doesn't distinguish colors between rewarding and already-rewarded bounties

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties, mobile-web

On [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212627/102999), I have a 200-reputation bounty active. To reward it, I would click here next to the answer:

[image: Arrow points to the lighter blue, bolded button to reward the bounty]

However, it looks like this on mobile:

[image: Voting and bounty buttons on mobile]

Unlike on desktop, there isn't a color or bolding distinction on mobile. **Can this be changed so that it looks like the desktop version? It's weirdly inconsistent and not as good design for being as clear as possible.**

Comment: Just to check, is the behaviour the same on the mobile-web as on the responsive view?

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301773/398063), possible dupe, since it boils down to the "award" button's color being the same as the "awarded".

Comment: @Luuklag no. The responsive design and desktop both have the different shades.

Comment: @Jenayah ugh that one is so confusingly cryptic and a bad dupe target.

Comment: @Stormblessed well true but it's already the dupe-target (of the dupe-target) of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316907/398063)